# Не подключаются стили, картинки и js Java Spring

Tags: javascript, java, css, spring, spring-mvc

Есть вот такая структура проекта

[image: Структура проекта]

MVCconfig содержит следующий код

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MVCconfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

При загрузке страницы не может подключить файлы с директории static
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*booking.mustache*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/main.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

UPD:
Странно, сейчас подключились .js-файлы, а .css и .png нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/main.css">
<img src="/static/img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы попробуйте указать относительные пути, а не абсолютные. Например `static/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css`. Или вообще без static `stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не помогло

Comment: Тогда ждем более опытных коллег)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй не ставить в самом начале «/».
Например: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/stylesheets/main.css">`
Проверь еще раз пути, папки и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы всё заработало и подтянулось - просто залогиниться надо и всё подтянется, потому что ты не прописал в секьюрити ничего.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]